# How to prevent stringification on an number when stringifying an object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am writing an API in `node.js` that pulls data from a db, manipulates it, and sends it off to be consumed.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    2734899508: "Chicken",
    2843594878: "Fish"
}
```

When I call JSON.stringify and pass the aforementioned object, I get this:

```
{
    "2734899508": "Chicken",
    "2843594878": "Fish"
}
```

I would like a string where the numeric keys are not turned into strings. How do I do this?

Comment: If you want to use JSON, you will have to live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test whether each key/value is a stringified integer thus:

```
if(parseInt(value)==value) {
    value = parseInt(value);
}
```

Note: using `==` here intentionally rather than `===` because we want to coerce both to string.

If, however, you *know* which keys/values are stringified ints, then you can just do the middle line to fix them.

I would point out that if you're sending this json to a browser or other javascript client, it won't really make a difference whether you have an int or a string, unless you always use `===`.

Comment: If it doesn't make a difference to the browser, then I am ok with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Numerics as object keys are not supported, they will be converted to a string key, you have the illusion of numeric I guess because when you do myObj[2843594878] it returns the correct value, but on the accessor too it is converting this to a string.

Comment: But I think `Object.keys(myObj)[0]` will convert numbers to strings anyway, so this might also not be correct...

Comment: You're correct.. I didn't test this 7.5 years ago .:D.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/) you will find that these numeric keys are in fact strings from a `string: value` pair. The parser is being lenient and converting them to a `string`.

As an object notation, your identifier being a number is going to be a little odd anyway, for example, if you had an object `myFridge`, it would be something equivalent to:

```
myFridge.2734899508 = "Chicken" // WRONG
```

However, you could still use the brackets syntax, as others pointed out:

```
myFridge[2734899508] = "Chicken"
```

You can consider other things like arrays to hold numbers strictly, for example:

```javascript
{
  fridgeItems: [ 
    [ 2734899508, "Chicken" ],
    [ 2843594878, "Fish" ]
  ]
}
```

might represent your data a little better.